# LoadLibrary in VBA returns 0 when trying to load R.dll in Office from Microsoft Store

Tags: r, vba, dll, windows-store-apps, ms-office

I figure out that some very specific machines were given an error when trying to load `R.dll`. At first, I thought that it would be a problem with McAfee because 100% of the machines that I got the error was caused by Dell laptops with McAfee installed. But later then, I find out that the problem was caused by Office that is installed using the Microsoft Store, instead of the traditional way (downloading the installer and executing it). The Office installed using the Microsoft Store won't let me load the `R.dll`. It returns zero in the following code:

```
Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long

Private Sub TestDLL()

    Dim ret As Long
    ret = LoadLibrary("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386\R.dll") ' returns zero
    MsgBox ret
    FreeLibrary ret

End Sub
```

In order to get the above code to work you will first need to include the following folder to your `PATH` system variable, *before* opening VBA:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386
```

The code above works fine in all Office version that I've tested (2007~2019) when downloading the installer and then installing (without using the Microsoft Store). However, if I login in Windows with my Microsoft account and then use the Microsoft Store to install Office the `ret` variable returns zero. When I say Microsoft Store, I mean this:
[image: Microsoft Store used to install Office and reproduce the problem]

My guess is that `R.dll` cannot load some dependent DLL in Office (from Windows Store) since it runs in a sandbox and has limited access to the file system and, perhaps, other system resources.

So, basically any information regarding to the below questions would help me:

1. Perhaps this kind of version of Office won't let me do this and period? So I 
   have to give up to the Windows Store Office version?
2. Is it worth trying to debug `R.dll`? I know that this would require some effort to compile `R.dll` and set the things up.
3. Can I put some sort of `try-except` in the `LoadLibrary` call to give a more information of *why* it cannot load `R.dll`?
4. Other ideas?

Thanks for reading and for any help given.

Comment: "I mean this" - so is it an Office365 or an Excel 2016 desktop install?

Comment: The desktop version of Office365 and Excel 20xx works fine. The problem will only occur when I install Excel 2016 using Microsoft Store.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a UserVoice support ticket then?

Comment: Could these machines have the dll under `C:\Program Files (x86)` by any chance?

Comment: You mean, to copy the `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386` dlls to folder `C:\Program Files* (x86)*\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386`?

Comment: No, I mean if the machines are a different OS bitness than the others then it's possible R would have installed under a different path - we don't *know* from the post whether the DLL is indeed where it's expected to be :)

Comment: I got it now : ) Thanks for rephrasing it. The machine (one of them) which the error occurs is a 64 bits Windows with 32 bits Office. The R is installed under `C:\Program Files`. If I run a `Shell "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386\R.exe"` command from VBA it works fine, meaning that the R is probably working and in the correct path.

Comment: If you suspect that there is a 32-bit 64-bit mismatch then actually dependency walker (Depends.exe) helps or DumpBin.exe (a C++ tool) http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/06/vba-python-python-com-class-has-own.html#How_to_tell_if_an_executable_is_64-bit

Comment: Why are you calling LoadLibrary?  Is this diagnostic for 32bit vs 64bit?  Because actually doesn't R ship a COM interface?

Comment: I don't think its a mismatch between 32-64 bits. But anyway, I tried Dependency Walker and there is no architecture mismatch. I think it's something that R.dll can't reach due to the virtual file system of Microsoft Store apps.

Comment: Actually, I use RDotNet in order to communicate Excel and R. But RDotNet fails in loading R at the same point (`IntPtr handle = LoadLibrary("R.dll");`) that LoadLibrary does in VBA. So I decided to take RDotNet off to keep things more straightforward and easier. That's why I'm using LoadLibrary in VBA : )